# When using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, how to change dialog title from "Open from" to "Save to"

Tags: android, android-intent

I am saving a file to a folder using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. When the open file manager pops up, some versions of Android say "Open from" which is confusing to the user who is trying to save. Is there any way to change that text to something useful like "Save to"? Is there another way to select a folder to save to?

```
Intent intent = null;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, RETURN_FROM_SELECT_FOLDER);
```

[image: screenshot of ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE dialog showing Open from when trying to Save as]

Comment: There is nothing documented for this, though it's a nice idea.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question:
`code` shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  // Select action services
`code` shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);  // Select the aforementioned file for uploading
`code` shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  // Streaming services
`code` shareIntent.setType(strMimeType);
`code` startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.chooser_backup_location_title)), RETURN_FROM_SELECT_SHARE);
Where chooser_backup_location_title says "Save to ..."